# How can I set a nginx index page for the domain name using Django?

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, nginx

I am using Django and nginx to make a web site.(Plus, uWSGI, and AWS EC2...)

I already set nginx for IPv4 domain(http://123.45.67.89), so I can get to the correct index page.

But I am not sure why I cannot do it for domain name(http://example.com)! I can just access "defalut page"(Welcome to nginx!) for nginx.

Could you help me to do for a domain name?

My Django project file(root) is `/home/ubuntu/proj/mysite`

My index page is in `/home/ubuntu/proj/mysite/taxi/templates/taxi/index.html`

I've set all in AWS Route 53.

Following is my `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mysite`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 123.45.67.89; #example

    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/log/mysite.access.log;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/ubuntu/proj/mysite;
    }

    location / {
        root            /home/ubuntu/proj/mysite;
        index           /taxi/templates/taxi/index.html; #location of index page
        include         /home/ubuntu/proj/mysite/uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass      unix:/run/uwsgi/mysite.sock;
    }
}
```

I don't know what I show you more to help me...

Actually I am not sure whether it is a problem in nginx or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood your question correctly then...

This is not a Django or Nginx issue, this is to do with DNS.

Locally, you can point any domain to any IP by editing your hosts file (how you do this will depend on what OS you are using). But that would only be useful for development and wouldn't be usable to anyone else.

In order to point a publicly available domain at a publicly available IP you need to have ownership of the domain and use DNS management to point that domain at the IP.

Apologies for the vagueness of this answer but DNS is a large area in itself and your question leaves a lot of unknowns.